# Usage of Sector/Sphere in production systems

Tags: filesystems, geometry, sector

I just found out about sector/sphere and am interested to use it in future systems.

Is anyone currently using sector/sphere (http://sector.sourceforge.net/) in production systems? If so, what are your experiences with it?

Does anyone know how this product will evolve in the future? I want to avoid using a system that won't be developed/maintained.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I am currently using Sector / Sphere in our system. What would u like to know ? Yes, The system will evolve ! The system does have a steep learning curve but the effort is worth it :)

Comment: Hope you could provide more details?